# Angular filter not working properly with Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I have added owl carousel in my project using Angular Js directive. Below is the directive that I have added to my project to use Owl Carousel:

```
 angular.module('app').directive("owlCarousel", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: false,
            link: function (scope, element) {


                scope.initCarousel = function (element) {
                    // provide any default options you want
                    var defaultOptions = {
                        items: 2,
                        nav: true,
                        mouseDrag: true,
                        autoplay:true,
                        autoplayTimeout:2000,
                        autoplayHoverPause:false

                    };
                    var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));

                    // combine the two options objects
                    for (var key in customOptions) {
                        defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                    }


                    //destroy
                    if ($(element).hasClass('owl-loaded') === true) {
                        $(element).trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
                        $(element).find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
                    }

                    // init carousel
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                    }, 10)
                };
            }
        };
    })
.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if (scope.$last) {
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
```

When I bind this directive with ng-repeat then it is working as expected but when I use any search filter then the carousel is totally distorted. I tried many approach like broadcasting but still the problem persist.

Here is the Plunker for my implementation [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wUpYfAZ0WEgiZgQ8uelV)

I think I need to rebind owl carousel when filter is applied but I don't know how to achieve this type of functionality.

Comment: Have you tried looking at others' implementatons? Quick check found this: https://github.com/emalikterzi/angular-owl-carousel-2. src/angular-owl-carousel-2.js might help there.

Comment: @Brian: Tested with version 2.2.1 but the problem still exists. Do you have any other solution?